# How to cut out a rotted portion of exterior corner vertical trim?

Tags: trim-carpentry

I have a rotted hole in one of my exterior house vertical corner trim boards. The rot is about 3 feet up from the bottom of board. Rather than replace the whole 16' board, i just want to cut out a piece and replace it.

How do i cut off a straight section without damaging the siding next to it or the other side's corner board? I can't obviously use a circular saw. I cannot figure out a way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great project for an **[oscilating multitool](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Skil-Multi-Tasker-Oscillating-Tool-with-Bonus-Blades-1400-03/203601099)**.

[image: osc multitool]

The front blade (and there are several to choose from) oscilates from side to side in small strokes, allowing a precise cut in both depth and width.

There are corded and cordless models availble in a wide price range. Almost all would suit for your type of project. I think you will also find many other uses for the tool, making it a pretty good DIY investment, even for a beginner.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only and not an endorsement of any product or source
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the oscillating multitool is the best tool for this situation.

In particular, one of the long narrow blades works well for cutting into a tight spot.  You can plunge cut directly into the required spot, without needing hardly any side clearance.  It works great.

[image: multitool blade]

I bought my multitool from a well-known cheap tool import company for about US$30, and they are even less than that when they go on sale.  It would have been worth it for just one job, but I have had no problems and it has continued to work just fine.  Easy to find inexpensive models by shopping on-line.

Comment: Great. I had thought about using that tool but was concerned that my wife wouldn't like me buying another power tool. However, considering i would be saving money on hiring someone, i may just do that. I've seen this tool usd on This Old House a lot.

Comment: You will likely save a lot compared to hiring someone.  And if money is tight, they might be available at a tool rental place (I haven't looked).